# In Angular, how do I run a method in a different component than the current component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How do I run a method in component Y from component X in Angular.

method in X component

```
  onClear() {
    this.editor.clear();
    // environment.templateId=0;
    this.openScheduler();
  }
```

like so Y component

```
 X.onclear();
```

Comment: Please describe the behavior you're trying to implement, and what's the relationship between these 2 components - for example, is X Y's parent?

Answer (score 0):

Use a service to interact between components or to use shared methods.

Answer (score 0):

If it's parent-child component relation you can do this like this.

```
@ViewChild('componentName', { static: false })
  component: SomeComponent;
```

And in template:

```
<component #componentName></component>
```

Than you can just:

```
  onClear() {
    this.editor.clear();
    // environment.templateId=0;
    this.component.doSomehting();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but there is no parent child relationship between them, friend.